# its showing error arrays dont have to many dimension,index out of bound;

Tags: c#

It's showing arrays don't have to many dimensions.

```
string[][] a = new string[10][];
int bound0 = a.GetUpperBound(0);
int bound1 = a.GetUpperBound(1);

for (int i = 1; i  <= bound0; i++)
{
    for (int x = bound0; x >1; x--)
    {
        Console.Write Line("  Page--   " + i + " -- PAGE " + bound0);
        bound0--;
        x--;
        i++;           
    }
}
```

Actually I have done this in using for loops requirement is to use array in my app here is for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < bound0; i++)
{
    for (int j = bound0; j > 1; j--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Page--   " + i + " -- PAGE " + bound0);
        bound0--;
        j--;
        i++;
```

Comment: k thank u got the output

Answer (score 2):

`string[][]` is an `Array` of `String Arrays`.In other words: [`jagged array`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)Not two dimensional array.If you want two dimensional array use:

```
string[,] array = new string[10,10];
```

Also see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)